# Read contact between two pins on port RS 232

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a sensor that will make contact between two pins of an RS232 port. I can choose the two pins that will have contact. My problem is I have no idea how to read this contact. On a PC I have to install a small executable that will read and write in a local file in my machine the timestamp of each contact. Then every 5 minutes write the contents of the file in a MSSQL database on a remote server on the local network.
I was thinking of developing it in C#, but nothing fixed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By 'contact' do you mean short the pins together??  Serial ports are not designed for this kind of use.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. How can I do that? How to transform this'contact' so that it is compatible with this famous RS 232 port?

Comment: You need an interface board, with digital inputs and a serial output.  Try Arduino (or the many variations), Raspberry Pi, PICAXE, etc.  There are many, many boards out there.  Also have a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I agree with Grim. You want a GPIO and there are a lot of options. Google GPIO to USB or an Arduino/pi as suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a hack, but you can use either the CD, CTS or DSR pins. You can read their state using the following properties of .NET's [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport):

- [CDHolding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.cdholding)
- [CtsHolding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.ctsholding)
- [DsrHolding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.dsrholding)

Where true stands for high (according to your port specification), and false stands for low (short to GND).

For a real solution use some kind of GPIO.